# October CMS sass folder

Tags: sass, octobercms

I am new on October cms, have just installed a project on my local system but I'm stuck on sass folder, how to get sass folder in the current project.

Comment: What have you already tried? Could you give more detail? Not specifically to octobercms, but you'll need to just compile the sass into css and then connect the theme to that css file.

Comment: I have installed October cms then create a custom theme, have also created gulpfile.js, install laravel elixir.
now I want to know how to get sass folder in the current project and get compiled folder with CSS and js in it.   I am new on October cms so maybe i cant explain in correct way.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm04CjmP8g8

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it in this way:

1.I created this structure:

```
app/sass 
app/scripts
```

2.Putted into my theme folder:

```
themes/myCustomTheme/app/sass 
themes/myCustomTheme/app/scripts
```

3.Put gulpfile.js inside **myCustomTheme** folder:

```
themes/myCustomTheme/app
themes/myCustomTheme/gulpfile.js
themes/myCustomTheme/package.json
```

4.Configured gulpfile.js like this:

Source folder is **app** folder.

Dist folder is **assets** folder.

5.And finally install Gulp inside **myCustomTheme** folder.

Comment: Thank you!! for your reply.  I don't understand how to get gulpfile.js, I have used "npm install gulp " command to install it but don't get gulpfile.js in themes/mycustomtheme/gulpfile.js.

Comment: You need create this file by yourself :) This is my: [gulpfile.js](https://pastebin.com/97GK32x1). Just download it and save as gulpfile.js

Comment: ok, thank you. And do I have to create compiled folder by own or through command?

Comment: Compiled folder is "assets" folder which is created by default. Look my folders structure [structure](https://imgur.com/a/eBG7P)